# There is some mistake in pagination code when using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the code of when I am making pagination using PDO, Then this let not run any code after this line code and what is wrong with this code I don't know, after this code all is working fine, So help me please, Here is Code

```
if ($search)
              {
                        $all_stmt=$db->prepare("select COUNT(*) from files where recieved_by like :needle or processed_by like  :needle or   purpose like :needle or file_name like  :needle order by date desc");
                        $needle = '%" . $search . "%';
                        $all_stmt->bindValue(':needle', $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                        $all_stmt->execute();
                        $all_post=$all_stmt->fetchColumn();
                        $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                        $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
              } 
               else 
               {
                    $all_stmt=$db->prepare( "select COUNT(*) from files order by date desc");
                    $all_stmt->execute();
                    $all_post=$all_stmt->fetchColumn();
                    $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                    $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
               }
```

what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: There could be many things wrong, but there's no way for us to really check that. You code is far from complete. This seems wrong: `'%" . $search . "%'` it should probably be: `'%' . $search . '%'`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a LIMIT [amount],[offset] in that query?

Comment: @DevionNL , i think no , because  i am creating limit here  and the i will use that limit when i am fetching from data

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  , sir when `if ($search) {`   will come in code then it will go in search case but it should run `else` case code, why that not , and i used that your suggestion   for needle part